# TomEE with Jersey RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, apache-tomee

I have a set of RESTful web services that are normally deployed in a Glassfish server.
The thing is that the place I work only work with Apache so I had to switch and now is where problems come.
I have managed to deploy a couple of RESTful resources and they work just fine (all they do is retrieve info from a database and return that info in an ArrayList of POJOs).

I have manually set libraries, even downloaded the damned JerseyClientBuilder but nothing of that works.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to add few libraries into your Jersy's classpath to support JSP and annotation configuration:

Maven artifacts:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And if you use Jersy embedded, you have to configure its JSP support of course.

Comment: The thing is I am not using Maven and hence I have no Maven artifacts. What is driving me crazy is that this setup works completely fine in Glassfish and it doesn't in TomEE. I don't know how to add those libraries to Jersey's classpath either. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

if you use tomee 1 you can't use jaxrs client API but if you use tomee 7 it is built in but based on CXF. Concretely remove all jersey and jaxrs api jars from your webapp and you'll get it running smoothly. Your code seems portable enough to not care of not using jersey.

Comment: It doesn't just give me compilation errors, but also throws some new exceptions, doesn't work

Comment: you should share it then, the code you copied works on tomee 7 without jersey/jaxrs dependency at all.